# How do I type punctuation characters on my localized keyboard?

Tags: linux-mint, keyboard-layout

I have big problem here. I was working with Linux a little bit (had Ubuntu 10 in old laptop only for internet) but I was never creating websites there, so I didn't need this keyboard shortcuts like CTRL + ALT + B ( **{** ) CTRL + ALT + W ( **|** ) etc. But I have now laptop with Linux mint 17 and I want to create websites there, and play some games from steam (dota, tf2, etc just for fun). I was googling for two days but I cannot find anything ...

Can someone  me how to make my Linux keyboard "look" like that in Windows? I just need that Windows shortcuts for creating unique symbols like #, &, @, {, }, ^^, |, ... etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried installing the Slovak keyboard on my Cinnamon and could get the `{` symbol with <kbd>AltGr</kbd><kbd>b</kbd>:

[image: Slovakian keyboard, right alt+B]

If that doesn't work for you, you might need to change the keyboard's options:

[image: options button in regional settings]

Then, choose the key that sets the 3rd level:

[image: 3rd level button settings]

Comment: Yes this works. I set it on left alt (its closer, easier to push it faster) but im searching for left ctrl option, but there isnt any left ctrl option.

but yeah, i finally can write that symbols !

Comment: @TomášMelich glad to hear it! If this answer solves your issue please take a minute and click the check mark under the vote count to the left, this will [signify to everyone](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) that your issue's been resolved.

Comment: Of course i do. 
If i can ask you last question please, is it posible to set up my keyboard to write this symbols  using CTRL + ALT + (key for symbol) ? Its weird a little bit :/
But im really happy this works! Helped me alot

Comment: Or just sympli disable that CTRL (left) because im always pushing it, and when i push ctrl and alt together, it wont write anything. If theres posible to disabling left ctrl that would be awesome

Comment: @TomášMelich I don't know, you'll have to play with the available options for the 3rd level. No idea why you would want to make things more complicated (why a 3-button shortcut when you can use 2?) but it's your choice of course. Also, I did not mean to pressure you to accept, you should only accept if you feel that your question is answered. I just saw you're new and wanted to explain how the site works.

Comment: Yes, im new, and yes i usually push accept or solved button when someone help me. Im not that dumb that someone help me, and i didnt answer or thank him.
Why? Because im using this shortcut for 3years from windows :) And its slowing me down using new shortcuts. Okay, thank you